# code not working after catching an exception

Tags: java, validation, exception, integer, try-catch

I'm trying to catch an exception when the value input by the user is not an integer. When a non-integer is input, the exception is caught but it doesn't go back to normal. 
What I want it to do is go back to how it starts when the program opens:

```
private void calculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{    
    int quantityOfBoxes;
    int width, length, height;
    boolean excep;
    do {
        excep = false;
        try {
            quantityOfBoxes = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText());
        } catch (Exception exRef) {
            System.err.println(exRef);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Values must be in integer",
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            excep = true;
        }
        quantityField.setText("");
    } while (excep);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of your while loop. If an exception is thrown, catch it, but don't continue the loop, since as long as `quantityField.getText()` doesn't change (actually you change it to "" in the catch block, but that will still throw the same exception), you will keep getting this exception over and over again, and the loop will never terminate.